# when does rails make path with a dot rather than backslash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

why rails is making a path like

```
/notification_templates/duplicate_me.1
```

it is supposed to be

```
/notification_templates/duplicate_me/1
```

my routes are

```
resources :notification_templates do
    collection do
      get :blast_send
      patch :deactivate
      patch :activate
      get :get_list
      post :duplicate_me
    end
  end
```

and my link is 
`<%= link_to "Duplicate", duplicate_me_notification_templates_path(template), method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary" %>`

Comment: `/` = slash, ``\`` = backslash

Comment: yeah thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the route is made for collection, it does not expect a template instance variable for id.

To make the route as `/notification_templates/duplicate_me/1`, make the changes in your `routes.rb`  like

```
resources :notification_templates do
  collection do
    get :blast_send
    patch :deactivate
    patch :activate
    get :get_list
  end
  post :duplicate_me, on: :member
end
```

and change your `view` to

```
<%= link_to "Duplicate", duplicate_me_notification_template_path(template), method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass a resource to a *collection* route. For this to work, your route should be defined as a [*member* route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) instead:

```
resources :notification_templates do
  collection do
    get :blast_send
    patch :deactivate
    patch :activate
    get :get_list
  end
  member do
   post :duplicate_me
  end
end
```

And the reason it translates the route to a dot currently is that the path helper most probably understands the parameter passed in (`template`) as a [format specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320263/what-does-format-mean-in-rake-routes). Formats are separated from the route using a dot.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass id like

/notification_templates/duplicate_me/1

as member for the resource you should make member routes. Please look in this [enter link description here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) . it would help you.

This way would help you.

```
resources :notification_templates do
  collection do
    get :blast_send
    patch :deactivate
    patch :activate
    get :get_list
  end
  member do
    post :duplicate_me
  end
end
```